# How to do properly google analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

Just faced the problem when I want to get google analytics about website speed and so on, but it gives error with no description

Like when I try to get analytics in “thinkwithgoogle” or in “web.dev” it just gives error after couple seconds after starting the test

And actually dunno what is the issue
If you know what is the problem and how to fix, plz say

Comment: It is pretty difficult for us to know what the problem is without the context. Please add the context to your question. What did you try to debug it, what tools are involved, what errors are you getting and where. Screenshots wouldn't harm either.

Comment: Can’t do that, don’t have enough reputation to publiah screenshots

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post this answers how to do it in your case.